# prove relative error of X+Y<= max( relative error of X , relative error of Y) known X,Y have the same sign

Tags: numerical-methods

Let X,Y such that X * Y > 0 (which means that X,Y are both positive or negetive)
Let A be the relative error of X ,and B the relative error of Y 
prove that the relative error of (X+Y) <= max (A,B)
I have tried to solve this question however I only get that relative error of (X+Y)<= A+B using that |X+Y| <= |X| and |X+Y|<=|Y| since X,Y have the same sign
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $X^*$ is the true value, and $X$ is the approximation, so that $A=(X-X^*)/X^*$, and similarly for $Y^*$, $Y$ and $B$.

Then
$$\frac{X}{1+A}=X^*,\quad\frac{Y}{1+B}=Y^*$$
and so
$$X+Y=X^*(1+A)+Y^*(1+B)$$
and the relative error is
$$e_{rel}=\frac{(X+Y)-(X^*+Y^*)}{X^*+Y^*}=\frac{X^*(1+A)+Y^*(1+B)-X^*-Y^*}{X^*+Y^*}=\frac{AX^*+BY^*}{X^*+Y^*}$$

I'll leave the rest to you. (Note, I have been a bit careless by not using absolute value signs, but the method is the important bit.)